# SQL Server deserialize XML with OPENXML

Tags: sql-server, xml-deserialization

I have read this documentation describing how to deserialize xml into table :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openxml-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

In my scenario each XML is a "table" with only one row, so I have written this code:

```
DECLARE @data AS NVARCHAR(4000) = N'<row ACOCLI="cod" ARAGS1="Some description" 
ACOFIS="cod" AEMAIL=" " ACOAGE="  " AANNUL=" " ANOMIG="Some Name"/>';
SELECT *  
FROM OPENXML (@data,'row' ,0);
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=94d10fa2f6c4f0eb580d5166c07f4553

It is not clear to me if I used the right root node, and in case 'row' is wrong, which is the correct node to set here.
The error I get also is strange, it talk about cast to int, but there is no int there, just XML.

The error:

> Msg 245 Level 16 State 1 Line 2
> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value to data type int.

What I am expecting is a select result like that:

| ACOCLI | ARAGS1 | ACOFIS | AEMAIL | ACOAGE | AANNUL | ANOMIG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| cod | Some description | cod |  |  |  | Some Name |

Comment: `@data` needs to be `xml` not a `nvarchar`.

Comment: Don't use `OPENXML` it's ancient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like what you actually just need to is `value` operator:

```sql
DECLARE @data AS xml = N'<row ACOCLI="00330" ARAGS1="Some description" ACOFIS="01266820248" AEMAIL=" " ACOAGE="  " AANNUL=" " ANOMIG="Some Name"/>';

SELECT @data.value('(row/@ACOCLI)[1]','varchar(6)'),
       @data.value('(row/@ARAGS1)[1]','varchar(30)'),
       @data.value('(row/@ACOFIS)[1]','varchar(15)'),
       @data.value('(row/@AEMAIL)[1]','varchar(6)'),
       @data.value('(row/@ACOAGE)[1]','varchar(6)'),
       @data.value('(row/@AANNUL)[1]','varchar(6)'),
       @data.value('(row/@ANOMIG)[1]','varchar(15)');
```